# Grab WooCommerce user's name to display in Contact 7 Form

Tags: wordpress, plugins, woocommerce, contacts

I am using WooCommerce and Contact 7 Form in a listing-style Wordpress website. Is there a standard method to grab the default First and Last name fields in the edit-account WC template to populate the Contact 7 form? See screenshots below. And help is appreciated!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help :

```
Your Name: [text* your-name default:user_display_name]
```

Reference : https://contactform7.com/setting-default-values-to-the-logged-in-user/

NOTE : May need to change for woocmmerce user

Comment: Thanks, I will try this and let you know. Yes, I was worried that the WC user might use a different variable, as the current setup defaults to the username, not the display name.

Comment: Ok,I think the woocommerce users are the wordpress user and so it will work as you need. Please let me know about that...